# Pandemic Legacy 2 objectives: build 3 supply depots and build 3 new supply depots

Tags: pandemic-legacy-season-2

We have been playing the first campaigns of Pandemic Legacy 2. A question on two of the mandatory goals. We have the goals:

- Build 3 supply depots.
- Build 3 **new** supply depots.

By building 3 new, we meet both goals and win the game. I feel it is not right to still have both goals in the game, especially since in the first months you only have to complete 2 goals to win.
Did we miss having to destroy one of these goals?

Comment: For Pandemic legacy, it's useful to know what month you're up to, please edit and include that information :)

Answer (score 1):

[Pandemic Legacy Season 2 Rule](https://images.zmangames.com/filer_public/38/ec/38ec25b0-821b-4c2e-b925-27c4a4038acd/pandemic_legacy_season_2_rules.pdf) The "Build 3 Supply Centers" is a "Prologue" card and you should have destroyed it before commencing January. The rule book specifically states:

> Use the Prologue Objective card during the [prologue] game.

There's a [full play log](https://www.girlgeekupnorth.co.uk/pandemic-legacy-season-2-walkthrough/) (Warning Spoilers) that never has two build supply centers objectives in play and that is my recollection of the game as well.